# Nested route in a modal box?

Tags: ember.js, routes, modal-dialog, nested

How can I get this nested route to display in a modal box but still be a nested route so that the URL still updates with the ID of the recipe? I've been tinkering with it for some time and can't seem to wrap my mind around how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

The nested route/path can only work from the application down.  That means there needs to be a direct path from your deepest path to the application.  So if your modal is dynamic it won't work.  If it's just part of the path, then it will work.

Here's an example, albeit ugly, but css isn't my thing

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/iROGiqa/1/edit